Starship (bash) in .devcontainer: if-statement returns 'unexpected end of file'
Inside my devcontainer I use a docker-compose.yaml to bind /home/vscode/.bashrc with a volume to my workspace file .bashrc:
volumes:
  - ../:/workspaces:cached
  - ../.bashrc:/home/vscode/.bashrc

I would like to check if starship is already installed, if so then use it with the command eval "$(starship init bash)" otherwise instruct how to install starship:
#!/bin/bash   
if [ -e /usr/local/bin/starship ];
then
    echo "starship installed"
    eval "$(starship init bash)"
else
    echo "please install starship with the following command:"
    echo "curl -sS https://starship.rs/install.sh | sh"
fi

The strange thing is, that if I write this code into my .bashrc file it says:

bash: /home/vscode/.bashrc: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file

If I put the same code into hello.sh then the if statement gets evaluated nicely, but it would not activate my starship eval "$(starship init bash)", which in turn works in my .bashrc file as expected.
I would like to know why that if statement does not work in my .bashrc file, but the same code works with bash hello.sh.
edit:
based on the suggestions in the comments below, I enclose the complete .bashrc-file:
#!/bin/bash
set -x
if [ -e /usr/local/bin/starship ];
then
    echo "starship installed"
    eval "$(starship init bash)"
else
    echo "please install starship with the following command:"
    echo "curl -sS https://starship.rs/install.sh | sh"
fi

After I open a new shell, it says:

: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: /home/vscode/.bashrc: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: /home/vscode/.bashrc: line 10: `fi'

For my hello.sh-file the set -x command works as expected:
+ '[' -e /usr/local/bin/starship ']'
+ echo 'starship installed'
> starship installed

To make shure, that the the file .bashrc does not have injected CRs I enclose also the output for od -c .bashrc, as suggested in this thread:
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n   s   e   t
0000020       -   x  \r  \n   i   f       [       -   e       /   u   s
0000040   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   b   i   n   /   s   t   a   r
0000060   s   h   i   p       ]   ;  \r  \n   t   h   e   n  \r  \n    
0000100               e   c   h   o       "   s   t   a   r   s   h   i
0000120   p       i   n   s   t   a   l   l   e   d   "  \r  \n        
0000140           e   v   a   l       "   $   (   s   t   a   r   s   h
0000160   i   p       i   n   i   t       b   a   s   h   )   "  \r  \n
0000200   e   l   s   e  \r  \n                   e   c   h   o       "
0000220   p   l   e   a   s   e       i   n   s   t   a   l   l       s
0000240   t   a   r   s   h   i   p       w   i   t   h       t   h   e
0000260       f   o   l   l   o   w   i   n   g       c   o   m   m   a
0000300   n   d   :   "  \r  \n                   e   c   h   o       "
0000320   c   u   r   l       -   s   S       h   t   t   p   s   :   /
0000340   /   s   t   a   r   s   h   i   p   .   r   s   /   i   n   s
0000360   t   a   l   l   .   s   h       |       s   h   "  \r  \n   f
0000400   i
0000401

The \r in the output above are an indicator that there are injected CRs from the windows editor vscode. Using dos2unix solved my problem.

Did running dos2unix or similar on your .bashrc fix your problem?

Thank you, indeed it solved the problem. Thank you!
